# Has a government of any region/country ever declared a holiday during any movie release?

Tags: public-holidays

A [popular joke](https://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/bangalore/When-Rajini-releases-a-movie.../article14499324.ece) in India is that when the actor named Rajinikanth's movie is released, it becomes a holiday. While I am unsure if the government does declare a holiday but [several companies did declare a holiday](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-36842524) on one occasion at least.

Did however any government of any region/country declare holiday for employees (i.e for public sector) during any popular movie release?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I'm pretty sure it would be a better fit on musics and tv SE

Comment: It is a question of governments. Governments do things. Governments increase tax, governments decrease tax, governments declare holiday, governments order extra day work, governments put emergency, governments ask for Twitter surveys, governments take suggestions before law implementation. Basically governments do something. I asked if some government did something. So, how would it be unfit here? I think you didn't understand the question and so you have downvoted me twice.

Comment: Are you going to tell me this question -> https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/69840/34768 belongs to sports se? They would mercilessly delete it immediately if you try. @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica

Comment: #Gary2 I can only downvote once, as can everybody else. Also, it's unproductive to assume who's downvoted or not, as it's impossible to say for sure. As far as I can tell, you are asking if there has ever been a holiday when a movie was released, adding the word government does not make it related to government.

Answer (score 4):

Chief Minister Sarma of Assam, India declared half holiday for any public sector employee on any day of their convenience to watch the movie Kashmir Files, provided they inform their employers and produce the ticket as a proof.

Reference: https://theworldnews.net/in-news/take-half-day-holiday-if-you-want-to-watch-kashmir-files-assam-cm-to-state-govt-employees

Home Minister Mishra of Madhya Pradesh, India said the police personnel would get special leave if they want to see the same movie.

Reference: https://www.prokerala.com/news/articles/a1257984.html